Как в Delphi проверить попадает ли значение в набор значений меньших чем 0 и/или больших чем 255?
Иногда бывает нужно проверить, равно ли значение переменной одной из нескольких констант. Если констант всего пара штук то это не проблема. Если их побольше, но они имеют значения в диапазоне 0..255, то синтаксис с a in [..] тоже работает отлично. Проблема, если значения констант выходят за рамки этого диапазона:
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  something20 = 20;
  something255 = 255;
  something2600 = 2600;
  somethingNeg = -20;
begin
  var a := 90;

  // Набор со значениями до 255
  if (a = something20) or (a = something255) then Caption := 'Ok';
  if a in [something20, something255] then Caption := 'Ok';

  // Набор со значениями больше 255
  if (a = something20) oor (a = something255) or (a = something2600) then Caption := 'Ok';
  if a in [something20, something255, something2600] then Caption := 'E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds';

  // Набор со значениями меньше 0
  if (a = something20) or (a = something255) or (a = somethingNeg) then Caption := 'Ok';
  if a in [something20, something255, somethingNeg] then Caption := 'E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds';
end;

Попробовал увеличить в настройках компилятора Minimum enum size до Word, но к сожалению это не помогло (хотя казалось бы сходная вещь).
Так как же удобно проверить попадает ли значение в набор значений которые могут быть меньше 0 или больше 255? Есть ли какие-то стандартные приёмы в языке или стандартной библиотеке? Хотелось бы обойтись без написания своих методов типа ValueInSet(.., [..]) или многострочных костылей типа case .. of .

Текущий лидер - ValueInSet, но неудобно, что его придется подключать во все проекты:
function ValueInSet(aValue: Integer; const Values: array of Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  for var I := Low(Values) to High(Values) do
    if aValue = Values[I] then
      Exit(True);
end;

  if ValueInSet(a, [something20, something255, somethingNeg]) then Caption := 'Ok';


Второй кандидат - case .. of, но он громоздок и плохо сочетается с другими условиями:
case a of
  something20, something255, somethingNeg: Caption := 'Ok';
end;


А почему нельзя инвертировать само условие (else) оставив a in [..]?

@DaniilLoban это же просто пример :-) В большом проекте и значений побольше, и проверки более комплексные.

Ну так нет серебряных пуль, комплексные проверки требуют комплексных решений. Если вопрос не отражает сути задачи то и ответ, если будет, будет такой же. Я бы лично не экономил на читабельности кода

@DaniilLoban вопрос отражает очень простую задачу, мне нужно заменить, условно, if (a = 500) or (a = 501) or (a = 600) or (a = 700) or (a = 850) or (a = 5000) then на подобие if a in [500, 501, 600, 700, 850, 5000] then без лишних сложностей. Для значений в интервале 0..255 это работает "из коробки". Возможно и для большего диапазона есть такая "коробка"? Поэтому и задаю вопрос на ruSO :-)

На enSO перечислены, наверное, все возможные варианты: What Delphi type for 'set of integer'?

Но я так понимаю речь не про множества? Опять же  решение циклами по указаной zed ссылке. Вполне годится на мой взгляд если не хочется хардкодить значения в коде.

Полагаю, наиболее короткий вариант -- TList.Contains(). Не знаю, можно ли в современных делфях инициализировать константный TList, но если да, тогда в Вашем коде можно будет заменить константное множество на соответствующий список.

Как вариант, можно создать TDictionary<integer, string> в рамках модуля, в разделе initialization его заполнять. Не знаю, насколько быдлокодерским это может считаться

Я бы тоже использовал словарь. По опыту, один из самых быстрых вариантов для большого сета.

Каждый раз сет небольшой (2-4 значения за раз) и суть как раз в том, что нужен однострочник для if-а, а не класс проверятель :-)

@Kromster, так и не будет класса-проверятеля. Получится тот же однострочник, только вместо внутренних констант будет глобальный (или в рамках конкретного модуля) словарь. Более того, проверок станет меньше, т.к. нужно будет просто вытащить из словаря значение или взять дефолтное. Но, конечно, словарик будет большой из-за дубликатов
